# Can I extract all of the words before and after a regular expression in a text string?

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame with 10 columns.  One of those columns is a long string.

1. It has numbers, characters, punctuation and capital letters in it.
2. I need to parse it into 2 columns, "before" and "includingandAfter".
3. The part going into into "includingandAfter" will always have 4 characters
4. The "includingandAfter" should not stop reading when it encounters punctuation

---

DATA:

```
rant <- data.frame(
  reviews=c("2022-01-22 DEAR diary, wish I could use SAS & b done in 10 min. with SUBSCR and Index"),
  ("2022-01-23 DEAR DIARY - I hope someone can help")
)

str_extract_all (
  rant,
  pattern = "(\\w+\\s){0,100} DEAR \\s?(\\w+\\s){0,100}"
)
```

Returns This:

```
[1] " DEAR diary "

[1] " DEAR DIARY I hope someone can "
```

---

DESIRED OUTPUT:

It should look like this, if we parsed on "DEAR" (without dots)

```
before  ...............        includingandafter
2022-01-22  ..........         DEAR diary, wish I ....   
2022-01-23  ...........        DEAR DIARY - I hope someo...


But ..... :
```

I need to parse on a regular express instead of a constant word, such that "DEAR" would be replaced with any 4 lowercase letters in a row

```
     str_extract_all (
        rant,
        pattern = "(\\w+\\s){0,100} DEAR \\s?(\\w+\\s){0,100}"
      )
```

BECOMES

```
      str_extract_all (
        rant,
        pattern = "(\\w+\\s){0,10} "\\s[A-Za-z]{4}"  \\s?(\\w+\\s){0,10}"
      )
```

but this errors out.

I tried this:

```
      str_extract_all (
        rant,
        pattern = "(\\w+\\s){0,10} "\\s[A-Za-z]{4}"  \\s?(\\w+\\s){0,10}"
      )
```

But it errors out.

If I could use that regular expression, and read everything before it, and everything from where it starts forward, I would be in business!

Comment: What do you mean by 4 characters?

Comment: like in the example -- I want to split by this: "\\s[A-Za-z]{4}"

Answer (score 1):

Using `strsplit`

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(rant$reviews, "^((?![A-z]{4}).)* \\K", perl =TRUE))

     [,1]          [,2]                                                                        
[1,] "2022-01-22 " "DEAR diary, wish I could use SAS & b done in 10 min. with SUBSCR and Index"
[2,] "2022-01-23 " "DEAR DIARY - I hope someone can help"
```

Using `strcapture`:

```
proto <- list(date=character(0),f=character(0), str=character(0))
strcapture("^(((?![A-z]{4} ).)*)(.*)", rant$reviews, proto, perl = TRUE)[-2]

         date                                                                        str
1 2022-01-22  DEAR diary, wish I could use SAS & b done in 10 min. with SUBSCR and Index
2 2022-01-23                                        DEAR DIARY - I hope someone can help
```

using `sub`:

```
read.table(text=sub("^((?![A-z]{4} ).)* \\K","|",rant$reviews, perl =TRUE), sep='|')
           V1                                                                         V2
1 2022-01-22  DEAR diary, wish I could use SAS & b done in 10 min. with SUBSCR and Index
2 2022-01-23                                        DEAR DIARY - I hope someone can help
```